# JS: How to prevent losing session per refresh after logging in in SoundCloud API

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I'm making a dashboard and pulling some info from the SoundCloud API. I'm relatively new to this API and I got as far as being able to pull the SoundCloud Widget per track listed. My problem is that everytime I refresh, I get signed out (I think). Is there a way for the session to remain even if the user for example refreshes the page? This is what I have right now:

```
   function connectToSoundCloud(){
       //INTIALIZE AUTH WITH SC
        SC.initialize({
        client_id: sc_client_id,
        redirect_uri: sc_redirect_uri
     });
        //INITIATE AUTH POPUP
            SC.connect(function() {
  SC.get('/me', function(me) { 

        if (me.username) { 
            document.getElementById('btn-disconnectFromSoundCloud').style.display=""; 
            document.getElementById('btn-connectToSoundCloud').style.display="none"; 
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?client_id="+sc_client_id+"",
            error: function(result, status){
            },
            success: function(result, status){
                        //CODE TO DISPLAY TRACKS HERE
            }
        });
  });
});
    }
```

Any help is appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you concidered `jStorage`? Download it from [here](http://www.jstorage.info/#download). Import the jStorage.js file to your code and you are good to go. `<script src="YOUR_FOLDER/jStorage.js"></script>`
Then you can store the logged in user like this:

```
SC.connect(function() {
SC.get('/me', function(me) { 
    $.jStorage.set('userInfo',me); // store the user to storage
    console.log("Logged in userId: "+ me.id); 
    console.log('Logged in username: '+me.username);
    location.reload(); // reloads the page
    });

});
```

Then whenever you want to get info about the logged in user, just use:

`var loggedInUser = $.jStorage.get('userInfo');`

To sign out, just use

```
$.jStorage.deleteKey('userInfo'); // delete the logged in user
location.reload(); // reloads the page
```

Comment: This saves the user data being sent but does this also ensure they are logged in? Is there still upload and comment functionality?