# Stay logged into Soundcloud with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

Soundcloud has great docs and for client side auth I am activating this with a click handler on their recommended orange links:

```
SC.connect(function() {
    SC.get('/me', function(me) { 
        console.log('Hello, ' + me.username); 
    });
});
```

However if I redirect them to another page, the user is no longer authorized. On the server side, they allow tokens to be stored for Python, Ruby and PHP but currently doesn't look like they provide and API for Javascript (I'm using Node). Is there a way to by pass this limitation?

Comment: Probably. But it depends on how their library works.

Comment: Someone suggested local storage in another question http://stackoverflow.com/a/22231502/2639922 but I dont see how it would stay logged in